# Rogers Satchell Volatility

Tags: volatility, programming, implied-volatility, stochastic-volatility, algorithmic-trading

I am trying to implement Roger Satchell volatility in Go, but my results do not match reality... I have been at this all day, but cannot find my error. The 30 day Rogers Satchell vol is at 8.75%, but my output is 0.004858435700980119... The formula can be found here: https://portfolioslab.com/tools/rogers-satchell

````
func getRogersSatchell(class OHLC, period_length int) Volatilities {

    var vol Volatilities

    for i := period_length; i < len(class.close); i++ {

        var sum float64

        for j := i; j > (i - period_length); j-- {

            x1 := math.Log(class.high[j] / class.close[j])
            x2 := math.Log(class.high[j] / class.open[j])
            x3 := math.Log(class.low[j] / class.close[j])
            x4 := math.Log(class.low[j] / class.open[j])

            sum += (x1 * x2) + (x3 * x4)

        }

        volatility := math.Sqrt(sum / float64(period_length))

        vol.rogers_satchell = append(vol.rogers_satchell, volatility)

    }

    return vol
}
```
````

Comment: Hi: It's not clear to me why you have two loops. You should be looping over $t$ and that's it. That may be causing your problem possibly.

Comment: @markleeds There are two loops because I am trying to compute rolling volatility, where the period length is 30 days.

Comment: I see. So maybe that's not your problem. Hopefully Pleb's response clarifies what you did incorrectly. I didn't go through it but it looks useful. Let us know if that doesn't clarify.

Answer (score 3):

## An answer with R and pseudo-code:

As pointed out by @markleeds, there is no need for two for-loops, since you can vectorize the outer loop. You only need the last for-loop if you want to do rolling Roger-Satchell volatility estimates. **I cannot code in `Go`, but I can provide you with some pseudo-code**.

Let your OHLC data be defined as $X \in \mathbb{R}^{T\times 4}$, where each column is respectively the daily open, high, low and close. That is, $X$ is a matrix with the time-dimension, $t=1,\ldots,T$, as the rows and OHLC as the columns. **Constructing some pseudo-code, your Golang function should have similar structure as the snippet below:**

```
function RSVol(OHLC, n){

  ""Initialise RSVol to store numeric values:""
  RSVol = Vector()
  
  ""These are now vectors of dimension T x 1:""
  open = OHLC[,1] 
  high = OHLC[,2] 
  low = OHLC[,3] 
  close = OHLC[,4] 

  ""the inner part of the mean:""
  inner = log(high/close) * log(high/open) + log(low/close) * log(low/open)

  ""Doing a rolling mean depending on n:""
  for(i=n:length(open); i++){

    RSVol[i] =  sqrt(mean(inner[i+1-n:i])

  }

  return(RSVol)
}
```

Implementing the above pseudo-code in `R` and comparing my function to the Rogers Satchell estimator in the `TTR` package produce the same results:

```
library(TTR)

#first 6 rolling estimates with n=10.

myfunc <- RSVol(OHLC,10)[11:16] 
TTR_RSVol <- volatility(OHLC, n = 10, calc = "rogers.satchell", N = 1, mean0 = FALSE)[11:16]

data.frame(myfunc = myfunc, TTR_func = TTR_RSVol)
```

[image: results]

**The near identical results seen above, gives some validity to my pseudo-code and `R` code**. I have provided my `R` function in an appendix below. I hope this helps with the proper implementation of your Rogers Satchell estimator in `Go`. If not, then please edit your question and provide some example data or where to get it. Then we can do some output matching between the constructed functions.

---

#### Appendix: R code

I have provided my R code below for better understanding.

```
RSVol <- function(OHLC, n){

  open <- OHLC[,1]
  high <- OHLC[,2]
  low <- OHLC[,3]
  close <- OHLC[,4]

  RSVol <- numeric()


  firstpart <- log(high/close) * log(high/open)
  lastpart <- log(low/close) * log(low/open)

  inner <- firstpart + lastpart


  #calculating rolling mean:

  for(i in n:nrow(OHLC)){

    RSVol[i] <- sqrt(mean(inner[(i+1-n):i]))
  }

 return(RSVol)
}
```

Comment: Hi @StevenSemeraro if my answer helped you out, would you then please consider accepting it, by clicking the green tick below the scores? :-)